# Function not called from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to jquery.
I have binded view to model and want to read value from from one of property of model. But it is no displayed.

```
@model OnlineEvaluation.ViewModel.DynamicContentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dynamic Content";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContentId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DurationInMinutes);
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Content)        
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        <input type="text" readonly="true" id="timer1" class="timer" />
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).doit(function () {
                alert("Hi");
                var value = $("#DurationInMinutes").val();
                alert(value);
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>

}
```

Edit: 
 When 'timer1' text box is loaded I need to read the value.

```
@section Scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('timer1').load(myFunction);
        });

        function myFunction() {
            alert("Hi");
            var value = $("#DurationInMinutes").val();
            alert(value);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Alert message box is not displayed when I run above code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the `doit` plugin before calling it? Also are you getting errors in console?

Comment: What is `doit()`? If this is some external plugin, you'll need to include that on your page prior to including your custom script.

Comment: `$(document).doit(function () {` would plz explain more about this?

Comment: Basically I need to call one function once the Ready function is called. As I have said I am new to Jquery don't know how to call. DoIt is not external plugin. It is just the custom function

Answer (score 0):

Lose the `$(document).doit(function () { });`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Hi");
    var value = $("#DurationInMinutes").val();
    alert(value);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per comment

```
I need to call one function once the Ready function is called
DoIt is not external plugin. It is just the custom function
```

Just call your function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    YourFunction(); //Call your function like this
});
```

Comment: @user2323308, What exactly you want to achieve using `.load()`? You need to know that `.load()` is used for loading data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. see docs http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I need to call My function When page load is completed.

Comment: @user2323308, As I have answered. Just use `$(document).ready(function () {
    myFunction(); 
});`

Comment: Thanks it worked . But $("#DurationInMinutes").val() gives the previous value and not new value.

Comment: @user2323308, `"#DurationInMinutes"` is a hiiden field, You are not modifying it thus you are getting old value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39640/discussion-between-user2323308-and-satpal)